# Change Android Source Code

Tags: android, operating-system, android-2.2-froyo

I have Downloaded Froyo OS and i have to modify it. is that possible?

i havent do that before. i just download it..

If anyone have done it before, please tell me the entry point. Where to start and what to do?

I want to change home screen of Android OS. I want my icons to see on home screen.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is very much possible. Just stick to the documentation on source.android.com and go ahead. UI customisation should be the easiest thing to do.